# IEFI bind context

Tags: javascript, функции

Как сделать так, чтобы при вызове immediately invoked function expression сохранялся родительский контекст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = {
  property1: "test",
  method1: function() {
    (function(par1, par2, par3) {
      console.log(this.property1);
    }).bind(this)(1, 2, 3);
  }
};

a.method1();
```

```js
var a = {
  property1: "test",
  method1: function() {
    ((par1, par2, par3) => {
      console.log(this.property1);
    })(1, 2, 3);
  }
};

a.method1();
```