# Как вызвать функцию внутри самой себя, и при этом не использовать имя функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

Иными словами, где внутри функции хранится ссылка на объект этой функции?

Comment: Вы, случайно, не забыли принять ответ, который я Вам дал? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889096/iefi-bind-context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee), но использование этого свойства (`callee`) осуждается. Более того, при использовании "strict mode" обращение к `arguments.callee` вызывает ошибку.

```js
function withName(a) {
    console.log(a);
    arguments.callee(2);
}

withName(1);
```

Свойство `callee` существует до сих пор исключительно по историческим причинам (ради сохранения обратной совместимости кода). Дело в том, что в более ранних версиях языка нельзя было создавать именованные функциональные выражения, поэтому для рекурсивного вызова безымянной функции приходилось получать объект для вызова (то есть ее саму) как раз из свойства `callee`. Сейчас хорошей практикой является обращение к функции непосредственно по ее имени.